# Corrosion by O2 of Fe

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, material-science

After a Fe material place in O2 atmosphere it begins to be coated with an oxide film. We know that there is 3 types of oxydes on Fe: FeO, Fe2O3, Fe3O4.
After some time under hight temperature there will be Fe2O3 oxide on the surface of Fe. Why Fe3O4 or FeO starts to grow under Fe2O3? Which mechanism will rebuild the atomic grid?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable materials science, for which there is a tag here on physics. Now, the question is unclear, but it is on topic here.

Comment: Those compounds under the $\rm Fe_2O_3$ contain relatively less oxygen than  $\rm Fe_2O_3$.

Comment: @Farcher, that`s seems reasonable. So the answer is in the stechiometry